# how to forcefully stop user being page data submiting in jquery ui autocomplete?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I used jquery ui in my web site which is developed using mvc3. `I used jquery ui auto-complete mechanism.`

i used following jquery function-

```
/// script to load owner for owner dropdown.
$(function () {
    $("#Owner_FullName").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Employee/AutocompleteSuggestions",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data:
                    {
                        term: request.term
                    },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.FullName, value: item.Id }
                    }
                    ))
                }
            })
        },
        minLength: 1,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#Owner_FullName").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                $("#Owner_FullName").css('border', '');
                $("#Owner_FullName").val(ui.item.label);
                $("#OwnerId").val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            }
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item == null) {
                $("#Owner_FullName").css({ 'border': '1px solid #ff0000' });
                $("#OwnerId").val(null);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have shown Owner name in the text box and set OwnerId to the hidden field for further processing.

For handing situation that is when user type in textbox and not select item from drop down, **i used change event**, and on that event i used reset hiddden field to null and applied css to the text box.

**Now my issue is my textbox field is not required field, and if user type in textbox and simply submit the data then it should show warning kind of message and submit procedure should not occur until text box value is cleared by user.**

How to handle this ?

Comment: If I am understanding your issue properly, you do not want the end user to complete the submit procedure if the autocomplete text box is blank/null. Is this correct? If so, then why not initially have the submit button disabled / hidden and then display only when an item is selected? Note: you could also force a check to the server based on what was typed and NOT selected from the list to see if it is valid. If this is something that you want to do, let me know and I can assist with coding.

Comment: @JoeFletch: my autocomplete text box field is not required field. But my problem is when user not select from dropdown, then it should show error message and when user clears textbox then only user can post data. Is it possible to do with using jquery ? How to do this ?

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do so. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an error condition when a user simply types a value into the autocomplete box without selecting from the dropdown, you can use the `change` event of autocomplete to highlight this an update your hidden field.

```
change: function (event, ui) {
  if (ui.item == null || ui.item == undefined) {//I also use the undefined check
    $("#OwnerId").val("");//I have never used null before when using val(). But you always want to clear out the hidden field if the user does not select from the drop down.
      if ($.trim($("#Owner_FullName").val()) == "") {//check and see if the user cleared the field out
        $("#Owner_FullName").css({ 'border': '' });
        //The autocomplete field is blank. Then put code here that allows the submit.
        }
          else
       {
          $("#Owner_FullName").css({ 'border': '1px solid #ff0000' });
          //The autocomplete field is NOT blank. Then put code here that prevents the submit.
       }//close the if = "" statement
    }
  }//close function
```

---

Another option may be to check the autocomplete field on submit to see if something was selected, and if something was *NOT* selected, then you stop the post. You can check to see if the autocomplete had something selected from the list with...

```
$("#Owner_FullName").data("autocomplete").selectedItem != null //or undefined for that matter
```

---

Let me know if either of these work for you!